# ComboBox - how do I pass the value of the items in the comboBox to my property?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a property:

```
public override int Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
        set
        {
            if (value > MaxLength)
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "Canoes are limited to 21 feet long!");
            else if (value < MinLength)
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                "The shortest canoe available is 12 feet long");
            else
                _length = value;
        }
```

In my form I have a comboBox with the values 14, 17, 21. I want to pass those int's to my length property. How do I do that? I am using the code below, but it passes the selectedindex 0,1,2 to my property and throws the exception for MinLength. How do I pass 14, 17, 21 to Length?

```
Canoe c = new Canoe()
            {
                Brand = txtBrand.Text,
                Model = txtModel.Text,
                ModelYear = cboModelYear.SelectedIndex,
                Length = cboLength.SelectedIndex,
            };

            this.Tag = c;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedIndex`:

```
Length = Convert.ToInt32(cboLength.SelectedValue);
```

Since `SelectedValue` could potentially contain any data type, it's an `object`. You need to cast it back to the data type you stored in there, an `int` in this case.

Comment: I tried that but the value showing in the locals window says 0 no matter which value I chose.

Comment: Using cboLength.Text worked like a charm thanks.  Can you tell me more about using the ValueMember and DisplayMember properties? What goes in each one?

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the Education Grant!

Answer (score 1):

If you have set the `ValueMember` property to the combobox and the values `14,17,21` are stored as a data member. then you can use `SelectedValue` property. But, if you are not binding the those values as a data member of combobox then you have to use `.Text` or `.SelectedItem` property of combobox.

For example if you are binding the combobox like this

```
cmb.DisplayMember = "Length";
cmb.ValueMember = "Length"; //To use the SelectedValue property you must have assigned this property first.
cmb.DataSource = dbSource;
```

Then you can get the value like this.

```
Length = Convert.ToInt32(cboLength.SelectedValue),
```

But, If you are not assigning ValueMember property or you are populating combobox manually then you cannot use the `SelectedValue` propety in this case.

```
//If you are populating combobox with datasource
cmb.DisplayMember = "Length";
cmb.DataSource = dbSource;

//Then you can use .Text Property to get the value
int length = 0;
if (int.TryParse(cmb.Text, out length))
    Length = length,
```

If you are populating combobox manually. like this

```
cmb.Items.Add(14);
cmb.Items.Add(17);
cmb.Items.Add(21);
```

Then you can use both property `.Text` and `.SelectedItem`

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the .SelectedIndex to grab the text object from the items collection, and grab the .Text value and parse it.

```
int.Parse(cboLength.Item[cboLength.SelectedIndex].Text);
```